# When I bind <Destroy> to Toplevel widget, the bind function will execute 6 times rathan than once

Tags: python, tkinter

```
class Attribute:
    def __init__(self, pos_x, pos_y):
        self.attr_top = Toplevel()
        print(root.winfo_x() + pos_x)
        self.attr_top.geometry('+' + str(root.winfo_x() + pos_x) + '+' + str(root.winfo_y() + pos_y))
        self.name_var = StringVar()
        self.name_var.set('name')
        self.name_label = Label(self.attr_top, textvariable = self.name_var)
        self.name_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.name_enter = Entry(self.attr_top)
        self.name_enter.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        self.next_name_var = StringVar()
        self.next_name_var.set('link')
        self.next_name_label = Label(self.attr_top, textvariable = self.next_name_var)
        self.next_name_label.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        self.next_name_enter = Entry(self.attr_top)

        self.finish_button = Button(self.attr_top, text = 'finsh edit', command = self.button_close_top)
        self.finish_button.grid(row = 3, column = 0, columnspan = 2)
        self.attr_top.bind('<Return>', self.return_close_top)
        self.next_name_enter.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

    def button_close_top(self):
        self.name = self.name_enter.get()
        self.next_name = self.next_name_enter.get()
        self.attr_top.destroy()

    def return_close_top(self, event):
        self.button_close_top()

    def save_attr(self, event):
        name = self.attr.name
        next_name = self.attr.next_name

        print('jinru')
        name_font = tkfont.Font(size = 10)
        self.enter_text.insert(END, name)
        self.enter_text.tag_add(name, 1.0, END)
        self.enter_text.tag_config(name, font = name_font, offset = 2, underline = 1)

    def edit_brief(self):
        print('edit brief')
        self.attr = Attribute(self.widget_pos_x, self.widget_pos_y)
        self.enter_text = Text(self.window_frame, width = 30, height = 3)
        self.enter_text.place(x = self.widget_pos_x, y = self.widget_pos_y)
        self.attr.attr_top.bind('<Destroy>', self.save_attr)
```

if I close the Toplevel window, it will print 6 'run',and text widget also insert 6 times text that I had input.
[image]
[image]

Comment: where in your program is the `print('run')`?

Comment: Well, your window contains 5 widgets, so there are a total of 6 things being destroyed when the window is closed.  The normal way of detecting a window closure is to call `.wm_protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", func)` on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you bind to a `Toplevel` widget, the binding applies to that widget *and all of it's descendants*. If you only want the event to be handled by the `Toplevel` widget, the common solution is to do a check on the widget object associated with the event.

For example, you can use `winfo_toplevel()` to get the toplevel widget associated with any given widget and only perform your action if the widget associated with the event is the same as the toplevel window associated with the event.

For example:

```
def save_attr(self, event):
    if event.widget == event.widget.winfo_toplevel():
        ...
```

The reason this happens is due to how events are processed. When you bind events to widgets, you aren't actually binding to the widget. Instead, you are binding to a *binding tag* which has the same name as the widget's internal name. When an event is processed, the event is applied to each of the binding tags associated with the widget. Thus, if you bind to a `Toplevel` widget, you're actually binding to a tag with the same name as the widget.

The default set of binding tags for a widget include the widget, but also include the toplevel window that contains the widget. The full list is the widget, the widget's class name (eg: Label, Button, etc), the name of the window's nearest toplevel ancestor, and the special string "all".

In the case of a binding on `<Destroy>`, when the toplevel gets destroyed it also causes all of it's children to be destroyed. If there's a label in the toplevel for example, it will also get the `<Destroy>` event. Since the label has a binding tag associated with the `Toplevel` widget, the bound function will be called for the label in addition to being handled by the `Toplevel` itself.

Comment: I use follow ways to solve my problem    
    self.enter_text.place(x = self.widget_pos_x, y = self.widget_pos_y)
    self.attr.name_label.bind('<Destroy>', self.save_attr)
I just bind <Destory> event to Label wiget rather than a Toplevel window

Comment: @TheCrown: I have no idea what your comment is supposed to mean.